# TypeScript error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type ' User'

Tags: node.js, typescript

New to TS and first question here. Please help me understand why I am getting the error below and how I could resolve it:

> property 'id' does not exist on type 'User'

I have searched extensively on the web and SO to no avail.

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response, Router } from "express";
import * as HttpStatus from "http-status-codes";
import { body, param, validationResult } from "express-validator/check";

// Import Entities
import { User } from "../entities/user.entity";

// Import Services
import { UserService } from "../services/users.service";

// Import Interfaces
import { IResponseError } from "../resources/interfaces/IResponseError.interface";

/**
 * Returns basic data about the user
 *
 * @Method GET
 * @URL /api/users
 *
 */
usersRouter
  .route("/")

  .get(
    auth.authenticate("jwt"),

    async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
      const userService = new UserService();

      try {
        const userId: number = req.user.id;
        const user: User = await userService.getById(userId);

        if (user) {
          res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json({
            name: user.name,
            surname: user.surname,
            email: user.email,
            createdDate: user.createdDate,
            lastSuccessfulLoggedDate: user.lastSuccessfulLoggedDate,
            lastPresentLoggedDate: user.lastPresentLoggedDate,
            lastFailedLoggedDate: user.lastFailedLoggedDate
          });
        }
      } catch (error) {
        const err: IResponseError = {
          success: false,
          code: HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
          error
        };
        next(err);
      }
    }
  );
```

Comment: Could you please post your code from the file ```User``` and ```UserService```?

Comment: `const userId: number = req.user.id;` id cannot be found since the Request type of Express contains no `user` and therefore no id.

Comment: Does this work? `const user: User =  await userService.getById((<User>req.user).id);`

Comment: Thank you @mindmaster. i tried to post the code but SO wouldn't allow me due to long code. I tried to cut it down to a few lines but the system still blocked me from saving the new edits. Still learning but happy to be here.

Comment: @Seryoga, your answer solved my problem! I can't thank you enough :)

Comment: @r3dst0rm thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Try to add body to req:

```
req.body.user.id
```

Comment: Thank you! @Andre Moraes